# Unable to scan Cobol project using SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube, cobol, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan

I am trying to workout code analysis for my COBOL code with SonarQube. I installed sonarcobol plugin and using sonarscanner I am trying to check for analysis. when I do sonar-scanner in respective directory, it says success but unable to see analysis in SonarQube server.

Attached is my sonar-project.properties

```html
sonar.host.url=http://xxxxx:9000/
sonar.login=admin
sonar.password=admin




sonar.projectKey=cobol
sonar.projectName=cobol
sonar.projectVersion=1.0


sonar.sources=.
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8



 ## Cobol Specific Properties


# comma-separated paths to directories with copybooks
sonar.cobol.copy.directories=copybooks
# comma-separated list of suffixes
sonar.cobol.file.suffixes=cbl,cpy
sonar.cobol.copy.suffixes=cpy

 ## Flex Specific Properties


# retrieve code coverage data from the Cobertura report
#sonar.flex.cobertura.reportPath=coverage-report/coverage-cobertua-flex.xml


# PL/I Specific Properties
sonar.pli.marginLeft=2
sonar.pli.marginRight=0
```

Comment: Please contact support for commercial products.

Comment: COBOL comes with commercial support rit.... Btwn why scan COBOL I think you should start ditching them one by one and move to new tech, just my humble opinion. Cost to run COBOL will be higher in comparison with adopting new tecg

Comment: @shiva, why would you imagine that to be so, sounds absurd without considerable qualification. What if there are no "tecg" that you like?

Comment: @bill yes i almost spoke like person stuck by lighting. If some sort of ETL solution is devised to extract​ data, the limit of tech is only imposed by imagination

Comment: is that a free service from sonarqube @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam

Comment: @Shiva I am using opensource sonarqube

Comment: @pandey Sonarqube uses open core model. You have to get different sonarqube to even make the plugin work let alone licence... If you are testing reach their sales team for trial licence (I hope they'd give 15 days period)

Comment: The support for the COBOL language within SonarQube is provided through a commercial product developed by SonarSource: [SonarCOBOL](https://redirect.sonarsource.com/plugins/cobol.html). StackOverflow is not the place where you can find support for such commercial products. Please contact [SonarSource if you want to try out SonarCOBOL](https://www.sonarsource.com/forms/cobol.html).

Comment: Thanks @Fabrice-SonarSourceTeam and I got it now. So sonarcobol plugin is not a opensource and need to get license to get scanned. thanks for the comments

Comment: I solved this by adding sonar.languages=COBOL in sonar-project.properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from [the Author's comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43372127/unable-to-scan-cobol-project-using-sonarqube#comment74017579_43372127):

> I solved this by adding sonar.languages=COBOL in sonar-project.properties

Pasting here for convenience.